# Red5: save incoming stream

Tags: red5

We use Red5 server for video broadcasting. But periodically we have some problems with it.

Is it possible to save incoming Red5's video stream to file? It is useful to reproduce Red5 problems occurred during streaming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in two ways, one is by publishing in record mode and the other is by setting auto record in the configuration for Red5. The first option will only record the stream you are publishing and the second will record all streams no matter what mode is supplied at publishing time.

To set the server option, open your `conf/red5.properties` file and locate this entry, set it to true and restart red5:`broadcaststream.auto.record=false`